# PROLOG CLPFD minimize expression

Tags: prolog, label, clpfd, labeling

I have a list of variables *L* over a finite domain. For example:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

example :-
    L = [_,_,_],
    L ins 1..10,
    ...
```

Moreover, I have a predicate

```
pred(L,C)
```

that, for any assignment of *L* to values of the domain, gives a cost *C*.

The question is how to use the labeling feature of CLPFD to find the assignment of L that minimizes C.

```
example :-
    L = [_,_,_],
    L ins 1..10,
    pred(L,C),
    labeling([min(C)],L),
    write(L).
```

Doesn't work. It just chooses the first assignment (i.e. *[1,1,1]*).

Comment: Perhaps it's the only solution because 0 can't be used ?

Comment: joel76, you are assuming things about pred

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, `C` is already instantiated at the time `labeling/2` is called in this example. The goal then reads similar to:

`labeling([min(1)], Ls)`

and of course, no room is left for actually minimizing `C` here during `labeling/2`.

To make this work, you have to formulate `pred/2` such that `C` is deterministically related to the variables `Vs` via constraints. For example:

`sum(Vs, #=, C),
labeling([min(C)], Vs)`

works as intended if the cost function is the sum of the finite domain variables `Vs`.

I illustrate my further suggestions by rewriting your example as:

```
example(Ls) :-
    Ls = [_,_,_],
    Ls ins 1..10,
    pred(Ls, C),
    labeling([min(C)], Ls).
```

Notice in particular:

1. I do not need to use `write/1` because the Prolog toplevel will display the solution for me when I query `?- example(Ls)`.
2. I let the names of variables that denote lists end with an **s** in analogy of building an English plural.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why it doesn't work. However, In this case I think pred it too complex to formulate it via constraints. It most certainly must involve recursion.

Comment: Constraint reification is often useful to express more complicated constraints. If all else fails, you can also implement a custom propagator.